# Select n-th level parent

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

I have hierarchical data as follows:

```
+------------+--------------+------------+----------+
| locationId | locationType | name       | parentId |
+------------+--------------+------------+----------+
|          0 | country      | U.S.       | 0        |
|          1 | state        | California | 0        |
|          2 | county       | Los Angeles| 1        |
|          3 | county       | Orange     | 1        |
|          4 | city         | Irvine     | 3        |
|          5 | city         | Newport    | 3        |
|          6 | city         | Pomona     | 2        |
|          7 | city         | Pasadena   | 2        |
|          8 | zipCode      | 92612      | 4        |
|          9 | zipCode      | 92658      | 5        |
+------------+--------------+------------+----------+
```

I have only shown a sample of data here. I want to select for every location, its ancestor at a certain level (i.e. either country, state or city - of course states cannot have a county level ancestor, so no need to output state rows). How can I achieve this?

For e.g. if I want to output data at county level, the output would be:

```
+------------+--------------+------------+----------------+
| locationId | locationType | name       | countyParentId |
+------------+--------------+------------+----------------+
|          2 | county       | Los Angeles| 2              |
|          3 | county       | Orange     | 3              |
|          4 | city         | Irvine     | 3              |
|          5 | city         | Newport    | 3              |
|          6 | city         | Pomona     | 2              |
|          7 | city         | Pasadena   | 2              |
|          8 | zipCode      | 92612      | 3              |
|          9 | zipCode      | 92658      | 3              |
+------------+--------------+------------+----------------+
```

P.S. One simplifying factor is that ids are assigned level-wise, i.e. ids start from 0 and are assigned in increasing order till all the countries are exhausted, then states, then cities, etc.

Comment: See http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @PraveenPrasannan: I have edited the question to explain how output for a certain level should look like.